# What is and why is the fault that creates the Illegal cyclic reference error in Scala?

Tags: python, scala, oop, computer-science

I'm trying to understand it from the fundamentals perspective. The Question is naïve, but the answers will bring more clarity to people entering into OOP or new to the programming paradigms.

It started with python, when I tried to play with some OOP example code, like here:

```
class Student(ScienceStudent):

    def __init__(self): 
        self.name = input("Enter name")
        self.age = input("Enter age")

    def put_data(self):
        print(self.name)
        print(self.age)

class ScienceStudent(Student):

    def science(self):
        print("This person knows science")

student1 = Student()
student2 = ScienceStudent()

student1.put_data()
student2.put_data()
student2.science()
student1.science()
```

which resulted in the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "xyz.py", line 1, in <module>
class Student(ScienceStudent):
NameError: name 'ScienceStudent' is not defined
```

Now I did the similar in Scala:

```
object HelloWorld extends App { 
    println("Hello, World!")    
}

class Student extends ScienceStudent {  
  def study(in: String): Boolean = {
    if (in == "y") {
      return true
    }
    else {
      return false
    }
  }  
}

class ScienceStudent extends Student {  
  def scifi(): Unit = {
    println("I know science")
  }
}
```

And I get the error:

```
HelloWorld.scala:20: error: illegal cyclic reference involving class Student
```

Now, I'd like to listen.

Comment: If you are the son of your father how can your father be your son? Is that simple, subclassing represents an inheritance relationship between classes _(which in turn, results in an analogous subtyping relationship on their corresponding types)_. - As such, you can not say that a `ScienceStudent` is a more specific kind of `Student` if a `Student` is a more specific kind of `ScienceStudent`. You have, as the compiler explains, a cyclic reference.

Comment: Or put another way, this is how strongly typed languages work, and Python isn't a strongly typed language.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Is it so that we use inheritance only when we want a further classification/segmentation? Why it can't be done if two different classses meant for different purposes can find some of their methods mutually convenient/exchangable?

Comment: @lousycoder inheritance serve two purposes: Polymorphism, more precisely subtyping polymorphism. And code reuse, which actually should be a consequence not a goal, but many people use it for this, which usually leads to bad designs. - Not sure what you mean with find their methods mutually convenient / exchangeable? Care to provide an example?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I'm not able to provide a programming example here. Just the Father Son analogy. A software engineer Son easily inherits all the possible physical qualities, financial amenities and better opportunities for life from his father(family ecosystem) who is an old school person but not a well versed coder. Now father wants to at least be a good programmer for any benefits, so he can inherit(or possibly import though that's different) the capabilities hence methods from the son.

Comment: @lousycoder "composition over inheritance" there you have the answer to that problem and all problems related to bad designs around inheritance. - Also, your example is not really good in terms of modeling, a son and a father are both persons, that is their class. You do not create a class for each entity in your program, you create a class for each kind of entity.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thank You! I do agree about the example and it brings more clarity to a n00b like me. What are the implications if we use 'import'ance instead of inheritance? And more on Subtyping Polymorphism?
I'm trying for a better example: There is a family in the biological classsification of Animalia: Felidae, which roughly covers all species of wild/big cats. Now, there might be some methods which when interchanged, may make a speicific specie more capable and fittest for survival?

Comment: @lousycoder you are taking too literal the word _"inheritance"_ class relationship is very different than biological hierarchies _(many people argue that word was poorly chosen because this, many others say that not only the word but the whole concept of inheriting classes is bad)_. - You are asking for many things and it is hard to answer all of them on a simple comment, I would recommend you to search more on the subject of design patterns. Also, remember that while class inheritance allows subtyping polymorphism that is not the only mechanism to accomplish that.

Comment: @lousycoder in any case, remember that when we say `class Foo extends Bar` we are saying two things. First that all `Foos` are `Bars`, second that a `Foo` is a special kind of `Bar`. - Now, depending on the concrete meaning of `Bar` and `Foo` there may be many ways to interpret that. For example, `Foo` may be just an implementation detail and you may never speak in terms of it but just in terms of `Bar` _(this is common for interfaces)_. Or it may be that `Foo` is a `Bar` that can also be used to do other things, it may also be that `Foo` is one of the composite parts of `Bar` _(**ADTs**)_.

Answer (score 1):

A specific reason in Scala (ignoring the ontological implications of having a cycle in the inheritance graph) is that the constructor for a class `A` which extends class `B` must always call a constructor for class `B` in order to initialize any state of `A` which is inherited from `B`.